# How to make LEDs produce light like incandescent light?

Tags: frequency, constant-current, light, device

LED light flickers around 100 Hz and is caused by rectifying AC power. How can LEDs be made to emit constant light that comes from an incandescent element which does not flicker?

Comment: Use a power supply that does not flicker at 100 Hz, which is most except the cheapest units.

Comment: Yes, some retro fit LED lamps do flicker, but most don't. The circuits contain electrolytic capacitors behind the rectifier to fill the gaps. Those with constant current drivers "flicker" with very high frequency, which even insects will not see. Is there a special lamp that needs modification?

Comment: Incandescent lights do flicker. It's about a 2% variation in irradiation. (Not as much as LEDs, I suppose.) I have personally made the measurements, by the way. This isn't 2nd hand info.

Comment: To add to @Jonk's comment: if you have a model airplane optical tachometer, you can test it by pointing it at the lights.  In the US it'll read 1800 RPM (1/2 60Hz) in the two-blade propeller mode, and 1200 RPM (1/3 60Hz) in three-blade mode.  This was usually more inconvenience than not, because if you actually wanted to tach a prop indoors you needed a flashlight.

Comment: Not all LEDs flicker at double the mains frequency, so it is possible to drive LEDs without flicker.

Comment: If you ever saw slow motion picture made with incandescent light only, you would know that this kind of light does flicker too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, contrary to the assumption in the question, LEDs don't flicker unless you explicitly make them flicker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a capacitor.

The capacitor stores up charge when the AC voltage is at its highest.  It releases the charge as the AC voltage drops back to zero.  This keeps current flowing through the LEDs all the time, even as the AC voltage crosses through zero.

Most LED lamps have a capacitor in them, though some very cheap ones don't.  Some have a capacitor, but it's too small and the LEDs still flicker a bit.

Comment: It's not really about a capacitor, but the LED having a half-decent power supply, or maybe it should be called a LED driver.